# on click button not responding with keydown

Tags: jquery

I have following code:

```
 <ul>
    <li id="1">same html structure as below...</li>
    .....
    <li id="42">
    <div class="input-prepend">
       <button class="btn btn-small companyListBtn addMarkerBtn btn-primary btn-warning" type="button">   </button>                                                                                   
       <input class="input-medium companyListInput" maxlength="60" type="text"/>
       <button class="companyListBtn editCompanyBtn" type="button"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="42Div" class="companyAddressDiv">
       <input type="text" id="test" class="companyAddress" placeholder="Enter the Address"/>
       <button  class="btn btn-small compAddressSubmit" style="height:30px;margin-top:-9px;" type="button"></button>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>



$(document).on('click','.compAddressSubmit', function () {

    alert("clicked"); 
     //my logic going on here...couldnt mention everything...

    });
```

All the above code is working fine.... The only problems is **onclick** executes only when i use mouse to click on the button... but doesnt work with Keyboard Enter button... I tried
**.keydown**, **.bind** and **.live** and tried to use **listiners** but wasnt clear with them.... i know its not a big problem but couldnt get the head around.... any help please.... thank you

Comment: Where did you try `.keydown()`, `.bind()`, or `.live()`? I only see `click`.

Comment: I mean $(document).keydown,$(document).bind... i reason i couldnt use them was they were giving me unsual results with logic that i implemented...

Answer (score 1):

You could add the keydown to the .on-binding:

```
$(document).on('click','.compAddressSubmit', function () {
    alert("clicked"); 
    }).on('keydown','.compAddressSubmit', function(e) {
      // bind this on the button or directly into the <input>-selector
      if(e.which === 13) {
       alert("you pressed enter");
      }
    });
```

but a way better solution would be if you want to trigger the form-submit:

```
$(document).on('submit','#yourformId',function() {
   alert("your form submit");
});
```

Comment: I recommend using `e.which===13`.

Comment: @troy do you have an error in your javascript? Please check your console. This snippet should work properly.